# How do I specify relative file paths in restful web applications

Tags: java, rest, war, web-inf

Deployment of my restful application will be "exploded" from a single WAR file. All file paths will need to be relative and not absolute (Nesting from a single WEB-INF directory). What is the convention for specifying these files (such as .properties files .xml files etc)?

Example of wrongly specifying: `file f = file(/usr/home/username/.../WEB-INF/file.something);`

Example of what I'm trying to achieve: (From Controller/Servlet)  `file f = new file(file.something);`

Comment: What file paths are you talking about? Can you give an example? If you need to define properties file for this then there is something wrong. Files should be relative to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should NEVER specify a file using `/usr/home` or any absolute path. The correct method is using [ServletContext.getRealPath()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)

```
context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/file.something");
```

There is also [getResourceAsStream](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) and [getResource](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thank you for your response Amir

Comment: How would I do this from within my controller?

Comment: You can do getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(...). Its probably better to use resource as stream because you don't have to open the file this way.