# Access to WEB-INF in a Java REST WebService

Tags: java, sqlite, rest, jdbc

I'm creating a Java REST WebService which obtains data from a local SQLite database allocated in `WEB-INF/data` directory (This design is a requirement).

The problem is that I can not reach the WEB-INF directory. 
I think I need to get the absolute path but I don't know how. I'm not able to get the Application context to get the app root path.

I'm using jdbc to connect the database:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + dbPath);
```

So I need to assign a value to `dbPath` variable.

How to get the absolute path in a Java Rest WebService??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your answer well, try to use:

```
getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/data/filename");
```

Or

```
getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(...);
```

Comment: Thanks Tarek,

All that I needed was this annotation in the web service class:

    @Context
    private ServletContext context;

and then pass it forward through the user call.

Then only do `context.getRealPath()`

Answer founded here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708412/how-do-i-specify-relative-file-paths-in-restful-web-applications